# Gridview table data manage in different view add sub heads

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to manage the data of gridview in different format like add sub heads

[image: In this image data show of subheadnames's month wise]

code of this data :

```
 var data = (from r in data
                          join texp in totalexplist on r.SancPropId equals texp.AllSanchAmtId into list2
                          from l2 in list2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new
                          {
                              Id = r.Id,
                              FYear = r.FYear,
                              SancPropId = r.SancPropId,
                              ExpSubHeadId = r.ExpSubHeadId,
                              ExpSubHeadName = r.ExpSubHeadName,
                              ProposedAmount = r.ProposedAmount,
                              SanctionedAmount = r.SanctionedAmount,
                              MonthYear = l2 == null ? "" : l2.MnthYear,
                              Expenditure = l2 == null ? 0 : l2.Exp,
                              }).ToList();
  grd.DataSource = data;
  grd.DataBind();
```

But i want to show this data in below given form

[image]

i have try this code but stuck in add to subheads

```
var monthwise = (from t in data
                    group t by new { t.MonthYear}
                        into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            grp.Key.MonthYear,
                            Data = grp.ToList()
                        }).ToList();
        var allColumns = monthwise.SelectMany(d => d.Data.Select(s => s.ExpSubHeadName)).Distinct().ToList();
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Month"));
        allColumns.ForEach(c => datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c)));
```

Is anyone know how can i manage grid in this form ?